# c check integer

Tags: c

I'm finding a function to check digit in c, is isdigit only check 0-9 ? how about 10-99999?

i have an integer, e.g. 22, i want to check is it valid?

any ideas? thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `isdigit()` function checks one character at a time. If you want to check more than one character from a string, loop over the characters in the string and call `isdigit()` on each one.

Answer (score 5):

`isdigit` et. al are for checking characters. 10-99999 is no longer a single character. If you want to check that the string "8382820" is numeric, you have (at least) 3 options:

- Loop over the string, and run `isdigit` on each character (failing if one of them isn't)
- Use a regular expression (`"^[0-9]+$"` should do the trick, but not very practical in C)
- Use `strtol` and check that the end pointer is the null terminator.

Here's an idea of how to use strtol:

```
char* myString = "9823872";
char* endPtr = NULL;
long int myInt = strtol(myString, &endPtr, 10);

if(endPtr && *endPtr != '\0')
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Sorry, that's not a valid number\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

There are probably other clever answers involving scanf or atoi, but I'll just leave it at this for now.